# How to print all the elements that are stored in class Vector?

Tags: c#, function, vector

public class Vector < T>
{

```
private const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private T[] data;
public int Count { get; private set; } = 0;


public int Capacity
{
    get { return data.Length; }
}


public Vector(int capacity)
{
    data = new T[capacity];
}


public Vector() : this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY) { }


public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (index >= Count || index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        return data[index];
    }
    set
    {
        if (index >= Count || index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        data[index] = value;
    }
}


private void ExtendData(int extraCapacity)
{
    T[] newData = new T[Capacity + extraCapacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) newData[i] = data[i];
    data = newData;
}

public void Add(T element)
{
    if (Count == Capacity) ExtendData(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    data[Count++] = element;
}


public int IndexOf(T element)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].Equals(element)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}


public void Insert(int index, T element)
{
    if (Count == Capacity)
    {
        ExtendData(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }

    if (index >= Count || index < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

    int tmp = Count;
    while (tmp != index)
    {
        //shuffle
        data[tmp] = data[tmp - 1];
        tmp--;
    }

    data[tmp] = element;

    Count++;
}
```

**I am working with arrays and vectors. Just wondering how could we create a function which displays all elements in a vector. I am confused because of the data scope. I can write a function for a simple array but how do you do that when you have whole class?
How do i create a function that prints all the elements stored in this vector?**

Comment: i suppose this is C#, because it isnt C++. Please only tag the language you are using

Comment: private T[] data; is the field wich  contains the actual vector for the instatiated Vector class. But actually you got the public field public int Count and a public function to get items (your_instance(int item_Id))

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < obj.Count; i++) Console.WriteLine(obj[i]);`. In `public Vector(int capacity)` you should also set `Count`.